# How to set values after click in antd rules?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have the following error.

> You cannot set a form field before rendering a field associated with the value.

I was trying to set values on the input after clicking.

Any suggestion?

Comment: can you create a example on codesandbox ?

Comment: Hey, there. Can you show us some code so we can have a better idea of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to access the form element before rendering, which implies you have written some condition for the form rendering. 
So wait until the condition satisfies and then access form fields.